# how to make autocomplete in webstorm as in vsCode for react native?

Tags: react-native

how to make autocomplete css properties in webstorm as in vsCode for react native?

in vscode
[image]
in webStorm
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please follow [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35144](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35144?_ga=2.161222141.1945925524.1583136753-463929881.1583136753) for updates.

Installing react-native typings `(@types/react-native)` should make things better: hit `Alt+Enter` on `"react-native"` in `import {...} from 'react-native'`, choose Install Typescript definitions for better type information. See [more](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html?_ga=2.182545894.1945925524.1583136753-463929881.1583136753#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files)

**More Packages**

- [Styled Components & Styled JSX
  Kodehouse](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9997-styled-components--styled-jsx)

Comment: I created through npm install -g expo-cli for type-script the same does not complement. Probably have to wait until jetbrains does

Answer (score 1):

I used plug-in "Tab-Nine" for VS code and Atom . It is very useful for complete code with many language. 
Webstorm also, but I haven't experienced it yet. Hope you like it [It here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12798-tabnine)